# VBS Open a Picture Fullscreen

Tags: vbscript

Is there a way to open a picture, like a popup in 'fullscreen'?

This is my code:

```
intAnswer = _
    Msgbox("Do you want to open Welcome.png?", _
        vbYesNo, "Open Png?")

If intAnswer = vbYes Then
    Msgbox "Opening..."
    "open %userprofile%/directory/welcome.png in fullscreen"
Else
    Msgbox "Not opening..."
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Showing a picture fullscreen is not possible with VBScript alone. You need an application to do the showing. An HTA for instance would work:

```
<head>
<title>SplashScreen</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA"
  APPLICATIONNAME="SplashScreen"
  SCROLL="no"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
>
<style type="text/css">
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">
  Sub Window_onLoad
    document.all.splash.width = document.body.offsetWidth
    document.all.splash.height = document.body.offsetHeight
  End Sub
</script>

<body>
<p><img id='splash' src='C:\path\to\your.jpg'></p>
</body>
```

Run it like this from your VBScript:

```
If intAnswer = vbYes Then
    Msgbox "Opening..."
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\path\to\your.hta", 1, True
Else
    Msgbox "Not opening..."
End If
```

Comment: Didn't know this was possible in HTA Ansgar. Awesome!